# Access inherited form's property in method that takes a `Form`

Tags: c#, forms, inheritance

I have two similar dialog forms of the **parent form** `RegistryEditor`:

```
public class ValueEditor : Form {}

public class DataEditor : Form {}
```

They both have a public int property called `OriginalValue`.

I have a method in `RegistryEditor` that has the following signature:

```
public void ProcessOriginalValue(Form childForm) {}
```

Assuming the following,

```
var valEditor = new ValueEditor {OriginalValue=1};

ProcessOriginalValue(valEditor);
```

Inside `ProcessOriginalValue`, how could I access the `OriginalValue` property from the passed `ValueEditor` form?

Comment: _"They both have a public int property called OriginalValue"_ -- then maybe that property should be in the base class instead. _"public void ProcessOriginalValue(Form childForm) {}"_ -- why not have two methods, each taking a more-derived type, e.g.: `public void ProcessOriginalValue(ValueEditor childForm) {}`? Assuming there's common code, you can have the type-specific method read the value you want, and then pass that to a method with the rest of the implementation. As you can see, there are numerous ways to approach this; your question is way too broad.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I don't want two methods that took `ValueEditor` and `DataEditor` instances respectively since the code within is very similar. But I decided to move it to the parent form, that way the child form can reference the `OriginalValue`, make changes, then pass back the changed value to the parent form.